# JavaFX prevent new stages from stealing focus from primaryStage

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is there any way to prevent new stages from stealing focus from main stage?

I mean each new `stage.show();` steals focus from my main stage.

I don't want to mix my JavaFX with Swing, so there's no option for embedding content into JFrame. 
Also, it would be great to not use any Popup, just pure Stage.

Is there any external library that allows me to do so?

Comment: If you have a reference to `primaryStage` at the point of calling `stage.show()` you can probably get away with calling `primaryStage.requestFocus()` immediately after.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you for the response. However, it would be great to never lose the focus

Comment: There’s probably a better way to accomplish whatever you’re trying to do, than making many Stages.  Having many top-level windows is usually considered a poor design, as forcing the user to keep track of many windows reduces usability.  For instance, if the user is likely to only look at one window at a time, you could make them tabs in a TabPane.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a listener to the `focusedProperty` of your primary stage and request focus whenever it loses focus.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StageFocus extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final Button button = new Button("New Stage");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            final Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setWidth(200);
            stage.setHeight(200);
            stage.setTitle("New Stage");
            stage.show();
        });
        final Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(button), 300, 300);
        primaryStage.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!newValue) {
                primaryStage.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```